# How to dynamically increase the distance between two nodes in GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz

I'm using this Python project ["Family Tree Maker"](https://github.com/adrienverge/familytreemaker) to generate a family tree. It works with GraphViz, creates a nice DOT file and then a PNG. "Minimum Viable Product" check. It works :D

[image: Current GraphViz Output]

Now I'd like to make it a bit nicer.

**Is there a simple way** (e.g. not having to increase the length of the edge per hand) **to force the right-most vertical edge** (between Father1-Mother2 and Franz) **to be straight/vertical like displayed below?**

[image: Desired GraphViz Output]

Thanks!

*Edit: as correctly stated by @albert in the comments, webgraphviz.com displays the correct output while viz-js.com doesn't.*

PS: Here's the DOT code that generate this Graph:

```
digraph {
graph [splines=ortho];
node [shape=box, fontname = "calibri"];
edge [dir=none];

Father1[label="Father1",style=filled,fillcolor=azure2];
Mother1[label="Mother1",style=filled,fillcolor=bisque];
Child1[label="Child 1",style=filled,fillcolor=azure2];
Child2[label="Child 2",style=filled,fillcolor=bisque];
Child3[label="Child 3",style=filled,fillcolor=azure2];
Child4[label="Child 4",style=filled,fillcolor=azure2];
Mother2[label="Mother2",style=filled,fillcolor=bisque];
Franz[label="Franz",style=filled,fillcolor=azure2];

{ rank=same;
    Mother1 -> h0 -> Father1;
    h0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    Father1 -> h1 -> Mother2;
    h1[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}
{ rank=same;
    h0_0 -> h0_1 -> h0_2 -> h0_3 -> h0_4;
    h0_0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    h0_1[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    h0_2[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    h0_3[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    h0_4[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
    h0_4 -> h1_0 [style=invis];
    h1_0;
    h1_0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}
    h0 -> h0_2;
    h0_0 -> Child1;
    h0_1 -> Child2;
    h0_3 -> Child3;
    h0_4 -> Child4;
    h1 -> h1_0;
    h1_0 -> Franz;
{ rank=same;
    Child1 -> Child2 [style=invis];
    Child2 -> Child3 [style=invis];
    Child3 -> Child4 [style=invis];
    Child4 -> Franz [style=invis];
}
{ rank=same;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried with 2.38.0 and 2.40.1 and both didn't give nice results, with webgraphviz (http://www.webgraphviz.com/) I got nice results, but I don't know which version of graphviz they use.

Comment: @albert: I just saw this as well. This is weird indeed.

Comment: @albert: http://viz-js.com on the other hand gives the same output as what I have sofar. And it says in the package.json of viz-js, that it uses the "2.1.2" Version of viz.js.

Comment: I'm not familiar with viz-js or their numbering.

Answer (score 0):

As expected after discussing with @Albert in the comments, using version 2.28 of GraphViz, I get the result I wanted.

I created an issue report on GraphViz's Gitlab: https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/1627